# Following camera Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I want that camera follow the player. For this I use player's(in target) transform and change camera's transform.

```
public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    private Vector3 delta;

    void Start()
    {
        delta = Camera.main.transform.position - target.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Camera.main.transform.position = target.position + delta;
    }
}
```

This method works, but it's a better solution?

Comment: Arguably **opinion-based**.  What is _"better"_?  Have  you seen the standard Unity3D _smooth camera follow_ scripts?

Comment: I mean use anything like AddForce and velocity for Rigidbody2D.
I don't sure that this method not re-call calculate the physics.

Comment: Why would you add a rigid body to a _camera_?  Consider [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32791570/edit) your question to include your _intent_

Comment: I didn't add a RigidBody to a camera(it was example). I thought, that some method maybe exists, which don't use transform a straight. But your last comment, about smooth camera follow, help me.

Comment: Are you seeing a problem where the object you're tracking is a bit shaky? If not then I don't think you've much to worry about, that's a good, straight-forward solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes down to what "better" means, but generally doing a little interpolation to smooth out the camera's motion looks better (although for VR it's not so simple)

Something like this should work:

```
public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float lerpSpeed;
    private Vector3 delta;

    void Start()
    {
        delta = Camera.main.transform.position - target.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Camera.main.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(Camera.main.transform.position, target.position + delta, lerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just make your Camera a child of your Player `GameObject` in the Inspector, that way the camera would move whenever the player moves! :)